# the road to PC game developement

Tags: game-engine, game-development

I'm in my first steps in programming, and I learned c++ and I am good in c++ programming.

I want to be an game developer but I don't know from where I should start, I hear that c# and java is the best language to make games and i hear that there is many game engine but i rally get confuse.

What language should I learn and what the game engine should I choose ?

I hear also that using game engine is make all the games similar,
can you help me and tell me what should I do.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't appropriate to such questions, you will get better personal opinions if you ask that on reddit or any programming forum.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you know c++ really well then go for unreal engine which might be **difficult** to learn but it has a great **material** editor. It even has a blueprint system in which you can visually do scripting (which I find limited as a programmer). When it comes to beginners **Unity** is super easy with tons of tutorials and uses c#. Both are free to use! If you don't understand c# then go for unreal and if you can pay some money then Game Maker and stencil can be a great choice for 2D. CRYENGINE & GODOT are great as well. I'll recommend you going with unity or unreal.
Hope this helps.